# techniques used in digital watermaking

Tags: java, image, image-processing, watermark

i am trying to implement a new digital watermarking system,this is the embedding procedure

the reference paper is available in the following link

http://www.4shared.com/folder/UNjahlTS/_online.html

i cannot understand the embedding procedure so plz can anyone help,thanks

> private byte[] encode_text(byte[] image, byte[] addition, int offset)
>   {
>
> ```
>     //check that the data + offset will fit in the image
>
>     if (addition.length + offset > image.length) {
>
>         throw new IllegalArgumentException("File not long enough!");
>
>     }
>
>     //loop through each addition byte
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < addition.length; ++i) {
>
>         //loop through the 8 bits of each byte
>
>         int add = addition[i];
>
>         for (int bit = 7; bit >= 0; --bit, ++offset) //ensure the new offset value carries on through both loops
>         {
>
>             //assign an integer to b, shifted by bit spaces AND 1
>
>             //a single bit of the current byte
>
>             int b = (add >>> bit) & 1;
>
>             //assign the bit by taking: [(previous byte value) AND 0xfe] OR bit to add
>
>             //changes the last bit of the byte in the image to be the bit of addition
>
>             image[offset] = (byte) ((image[offset] & 0xFE) | b);
>
>         }
>
>     }
>
>     return image;
>
> }
> ```

this is the embedding procedure

Comment: Please use a different service for sharing the reference paper. 4shared requires installation of a suspect download manager.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm just replace the last bit from the image pixel and replace it with the bit from the addition byte which you want to hidden it in the image

The inputs for the Method :

- `byte[] image`: your image in which you will hidden your data,
- `byte[] addition`: the data which you want to hidden it,
- `int offset`: a variable will determine the start index which you will hidden from it (it is just a trick, you don't need to start the hidden from the 0 index , it's up to you).

Then you will loop on the `addition` array , let's say the first byte in the array is `10`
the byte for it is `(00001010)` this data you will embedded it in b pixel.

---

### Lets see how?

Assuming that the `image[offset] = 20` ---> let's say  `offset`=0;

```
int b = (add >>> bit) & 1;---->in the start loop will be (00001010)
                                                          ^
```

Then I will replace the last significant bit in the `image[offset]` by this addition bit `0`

`image[offset] = 20------------->00010100` , when I replace the **LSB**<sup>**1**</sup> by `0`

It will be `00010100---------> 20`

So , I will set the new `image[offset]` value in the array by `20` which contain `0` bit information

---

Lets say the **`b = 1`** , **`image[offset] = 20`**

So, when I replace the **LSB**<sup>**2**</sup> in

```
 (20)---->00010100  by the 1 it will be 00010101  
                 ^                             ^
```

which is equal to (21) , so `21` is the new value after you embed `1`

---

<sup>**1, 2:**<sup>**LSB** Means: lest significant bit.</sup></sup>

[image]